# Identify Two Different Columns with One Function

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the function that can identify a column by its header:

```
Function find_Col(header As String) As Range

    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set y = Workbooks("Template.xlsm")

    Set ws1 = y.Sheets("Results")

    With ws1

        Set aCell = Cells.Find(what:=header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        col = aCell.Column
        colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

        lRow = Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Set myCol = Range(colName & "2")

        'This is your range
        Set find_Col = Range(myCol.Address & ":" & colName & lRow)

        find_Col.Select

    End With

End Function
```

Then I call the function in the sub:

```
Sub myCol_Find()

    find_Col ("Product")

End Sub
```

The above works fine, but the problem I am facing is that if the column I am searching for is pretty much blank, excluding the header, then my function will only select the first 2 rows under the header. Also, a second issue, it selects the row just after the last row as well. So if the first row under the heading is `B3` and the last row is `B10`, it selects `B3:B11`.

As a result of this, I thought that it would perhaps work better by first identifying a column with data in it (which I know will always have data in it) then use this column to find the last row of data, and finally use the actual column I need for selection.

So I first did a test by changing this line:

```
    lRow = Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

To this:

```
    lRow = Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

And this selected all the cells in my searched for column based on the total rows found in Column A.

Then I thought instead of specifically naming a column, I'll apply the same logic of "finding" a column to find "Column A". So I have this:

```
Function find_Col(header As String) As Range

    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range, def_Header As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long, defCol As Long
    Dim colName As String, defColName As String
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set y = Workbooks("Template.xlsm")

    Set ws1 = y.Sheets("Results")

    With ws1

        Set def_Header = Cells.Find(what:="ID", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        defCol = def_Header.Column
        defColName = Split(.Cells(, def_Col).Address, "$")(1)

        Set aCell = Cells.Find(what:=header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        col = aCell.Column
        colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

'        lRow = Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        lRow = Range(defColName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Set myCol = Range(colName & "2")

        'This is your range
        Set find_Col = Range(myCol.Address & ":" & colName & lRow)

        find_Col.Select

    End With

End Function
```

**Extra code added:**

```
Dim def_Header As Range
Dim defCol As Long
Dim defColName As String

Set def_Header = Cells.Find(what:="KW_ID", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

defCol = def_Header.Column
defColName = Split(.Cells(, defCol).Address, "$")(1)
```

And changed this:

```
lRow = Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

To this:

```
lRow = Range(defColName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Now, I am getting an error at the line:

```
defCol = def_Header.Column
```

Error:

> Object variable of With block variable not set

I don't quite know what the problem is as it didn't give me this error previously when I defined `aCell`.

So currently, I am facing two issues:

1. Selection is selecting one extra cell than what is needed
2. I don't know why I am receiving the above error

Comment: To avoid the extra row just remove the `+1`  You're not scoping anything inside your `With` block (ie. you should be prefixing Range etc with `.`

Comment: OMG. ;/ Lo, I feel like a fool. Keep missing these simple issues. Thank you @TimWilliams :)

Comment: `def_Header` will be `Nothing` if the header is not found, so you need to check for that.

Comment: Ahhh! The header name wasn't updated correctly. Thank you for the help @TimWilliams :)

Comment: As a bonus, you can simply use `find_Col("Product").Select` in your main code. This way you can avoid using `.Select` in your function which may have unintended consequences in the future. Actually, you can use any of the Range properties and methods on the function call line because the return of the function is a Range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

**EDIT:** updated to deal with cases where the header is found but there is no data

```
Function find_Col(header As String) As Range

    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, rng As Range

    With Workbooks("Template.xlsm").Sheets("Results")

        Set aCell = .Cells.Find(what:=header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set aCell = aCell.Offset(1, 0)
            Set bCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, aCell.Column).End(xlUp)
            If bCell.Row > aCell.Row Then
                Set rng = .Range(aCell, bCell)  'column has some content
            Else
                Set rng = aCell 'or nothing?     'column has no content...
            End If
        End If      
    End With

    Set find_col = rng
End Function
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you :)

Comment: ++ @EitelDagnin: You will still have to do one extra check.. `If Not find_Col("Product") Is nothing Then` That is because if the header is not found then `Set find_col = rng` will equate to `Set find_col = Nothing` and you will get that error again..